# change role to all server members

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to create a discord bot that, after receiving a message from the admin, changes the role of all server members (excluding the admin) from @everyone to @newrole.

I tried this code but there is an error:

> role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="newrole")
>   AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

I use the latest version of discord and Python 3.6.

```
server = client.get_guild(int(server-id))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
if message.content.startswith('change role'):
    await message.author.send("Change the role from @everyone to @newrole")
    role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="newrole")
    for member in server.members:
        await member.add_roles(role)
```

Answer (score 1):

All members have the `everyone` role at all times.  Members can have multiple roles, however, so you can also give them your new role.  There is no coroutine for bulk assigning roles, so you have to do it member by member:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('change role'):
        await message.author.send("Change the role from @everyone to @newrole")
        role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="newrole")
        for member in message.guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(role)
```

Comment: I tried this code but there is an error:                                                                            role = discord.utils.get(message.guild.roles, name="@newrole")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

Comment: Are you sending a private message to the bot to trigger the command?  Then it won't know which server to act on.

Comment: Yes I send a private message from admin to the bot

Comment: Does your code have a definition for `server` that you can use instead of `message.guild`?

Comment: No, it doesn't... How can I make it?

Comment: What do you know about the server when the person sends you a message?  Is your bot only a member of one server? You can use `client.get_guild(id)` to use the servers id to get the `Guild` object

Comment: I define server = client.get_guild(server-id) and I use this instead of message.guild. But there is an error:                                                              role = discord.utils.get(server.roles, name="newrole")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'

Comment: `get_guild` returned None, make sure you pass the id as an int.

Comment: I put server = client.get_guild(int(server-id)) but there is the same error